# Comparing NSNumber property wrapping NS_ENUM in Swift without using rawValue

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

We have some existing code in ObjC that does JSON serialization/deserialization.  In one of these data object's .h file, we have something like:

**DataObject.h**

```
@class DataObject
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FriendStatus)
{
    FriendStatusMyself = -1,
    FriendStatusNotFriends = 0,
    FriendStatusFriends = 1,
    FriendStatusPendingIncoming = 2,
    FriendStatusPendingOutgoing = 3
};

@interface DataObject : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *friendStatus;
// more stuff...
@end
```

Now this works great with JSON serialization and all is right with the world.  Well somewhat.

In my swift class, I want to use the DataObject, but reference `friendStatus` as a 
`FriendStatus` enum, so I end up using `.rawValue` a lot.  For example

**RandomClass.swift**

```
if (dataObject.friendStatus == FriendStatus.PendingIncoming.rawValue) {
    // do something
}
```

This works, and arguably this is relatively minor, but using `.rawValue` all over the place seems yucky<sup>(tm)</sup>.  Is there a way to do a conversion so `DataObject.friendStatus` is truly a FriendStatus enum and I can stop using `.rawValue` in swift?

Unfortunately, I'm limited in the changes I can make on my model (DataObject) since it's existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define an extension for the DataObject class that defines a getter to do the unwrapping for you.

```
extension DataObject {
    var friendStatusEnum: FriendStatus {
        return FriendStatus(rawValue: friendStatus.integerValue)!
    }
}
```

Note that it implicitly unwraps the enum, which means if for some reason the NSNumber has a value that doesn't match the enum it will crash. A more robust version would check for nil from the init and return a sensible default.

Comment: Both @Code Different's and this answer were both good.  But I ended up using this method to solve my particular problem.  It meant a bit of change in my codebase to use the new friendStatusEnum, but worked great otherwise.  Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 3):

Because `NSNumber` is not the same as `NSInteger`. `NSNumber` is a reference type, while `NSInteger` is a value type, which resolves to `Int32` or `Int64` depending on your platform.

Tell Swift how to compare an `NSNumber` with a `FriendStatus`:

```
public func == (lhs: NSNumber, rhs: FriendStatus) -> Bool {
    return lhs.integerValue == rhs.rawValue
}

public func == (lhs: FriendStatus, rhs: NSNumber) -> Bool {
    return rhs.integerValue == lhs.rawValue
}
```

Comment: I like this one. I'm generally not a fan of operator overloading, but in this case it's a good fit.  One other thing, is there a way to get an operator overload to work within a switch statement? I could change the switch to a bunch of ifs, but that's kinda yucky too.  :)  Thanks!